# UFT/QTP = Not getting updated value from Excel

Tags: excel, qtp, hp-uft

We are using UFT12.51 for test automation. 
We are facing below issue ONLY when we put our scripts for night execution.

We have used '=Today()' function in excel to get today's date.
Today's date is 19 July 2016. When we put scripts for night execution, after 11:59PM excel should give updated date [ 20 July 2016] but it send 19 July 2016 & due which our validation get failed.

What can be done to get updated value from Excel after 11:59PM?

Comment: are you talking about the time between 23:59 and 0:00?

Comment: Yes..After 23:59 when day get changed

Comment: the day changes at 0:00! 23:59:59.999999 is still the old day. If the system clock is set correctly, excel will return the new day starting exactly at 0:00.

Answer (score 4):

Excel calculation of formulas doesn't work in datatables for UFT - it just reads the values and doesn't do the recalculation that you are looking for.  You would be better placed not leaving a current date value in a datatable and instead simply using the vbscript `Date` function for the current date, which is available in UFT/QTP and would correctly set the date as you require.

Comment: I think the issue is that: when you import the datasheet into DataTable within QTP, then the spreadsheet isn't actually under Excel's control - it's now under QTP's control (it's just excel DATA that has been imported), and QTP isn't as accurate as Excel at handling formulas.  One option would be to save the datasheet back to disk, then REIMPORT it after midnight... that should cause QTP to properly evaluate the =Now() or =Today() excel function.  Better yet, just use VBScript's today function, as Dave said.

Answer (score 0):

@onkar : Simply you can do the following things which will work
1)Import the excel sheet once again in the code before the date validation part if all the data are imported in start of the execution. so when the excel is getting imported it will refresh the new data.
                                  Or
2)Use the vb function code to get the dates before the validation line 
var= DateAdd("d", 0, Date)

P.S: Even in our project it created a issue during overnight execution. In all the scenarios of date, time and the value which keep on changing time to time need to be imported before the usage